# Rsyslog tcp forward failed

Tags: rsyslog, centos8

I've this sub configuration :

UDP configuration : Works

```
template(name="template1" type="string" string="/var/log/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%HOSTNAME%/%HOSTNAME%-%FROMHOST-IP%.log")
ruleset(name="rule1"){
                action(type="omfile" dynaFile="template1")
                action(type="omfwd" protocol="udp" target="10.10.10.1" port="1025")
}
input(type="imudp" port="1025" ruleset="rule1")
```

TCP configuration :

Configuration 1 : Failed

```
template(name="template1" type="string" string="/var/log/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%HOSTNAME%/%HOSTNAME%-%FROMHOST-IP%.log")
ruleset(name="rule1"){
                action(type="omfile" dynaFile="template1")
                action(type="omfwd" protocol="tcp" target="10.10.10.1" port="1025")
}
input(type="imudp" port="1025" ruleset="rule1")
```

Configuration 2 : Failed

```
template(name="template1" type="string" string="/var/log/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%HOSTNAME%/%HOSTNAME%-%FROMHOST-IP%.log")
ruleset(name="rule1"){
                action(type="omfile" dynaFile="template1")
                action(type="omfwd" queue.type="linkedlist" queue.filename="queueing" action.resumeRetryCount="-1" queue.saveOnShutdown="on" protocol="tcp" target="10.10.10.1" port="1025")
}
input(type="imudp" port="1025" ruleset="rule1")
```

Someone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: on host ```10.10.10.1``` do a ```netstat -an | grep 1025``` and make sure it's listening for TCP requests.  Just because the remote end is listening for UDP does not mean it's listening for TCP.

Comment: Yes, I've an open UDP AND TCP socket on 1025 on the remote machine.

Comment: Are you using SELinux?  Check file /var/log/audit/audit.log for any indications on traffic being blocked.  Can you telnet to port 1025 on the remote from the client host?  Any firewall rules on the client host?

Comment: I disabled SELinux and firewalld on "client and server"